# Query Custom Post Type that doesn't have a specific Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, query

I have a CPT 'catalog' and a custom taxonomy 'catalog_category' attached to it.

I need to query for all 'catalog' items, that don't have any values of 'catalog_category' selected.

These arguments make a query for all catalog items.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'catalog',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
```

What arguments I need to add to exclude items with 'catalog_category'?

Comment: Not exactly the same but it helped. I took your response and modified it a little (Short syntax for arrays not working in PHP 5.3). [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/nLYxNqpi)

Comment: You shouldn't be running any PHP version older than 5.6. PHP 5.5 will reach EOL in July, all other versions has already reached EOL which puts your site at huge risk. Since PHP 5.4 no one is using old array syntax anymore. ;-)

Comment: You're talking like it's my choice. I run whatever hosting provider have. ;-)

Comment: Maybe time to change then ;-). You should ask your hosting provider if they can't upgrade. Using EOL'ed software can really affect your website's security negatively. Good Luck ;-)